# Partial View error HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-5.2

My application is running on MVC 5 . Recently I upgraded the Npgsql nuget package version and after that started getting below error in the application.

**Error :- **
HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete with partail view.
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Below is the code samples used in the application.

**Cshtml page :-**

```
Html.RenderAction("GetData", "ControllerName")
```

**Controller :-** Action method is having async and await

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetData()
{           
   var data =  await _service.Data();
   return View("Data", data );
}
```

This code was running fine but getting these exceptions after upgrading the Npgsql version.

I have tried making action method synchronous by removing the async and used .Result instead of await but execution is stuck on _service.Data().Result .

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{           
   var data =  _service.Data().Result;
   return View("Data", data );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET (pre-Core) does not support asynchronous child actions. There is no workaround. To solve this, you'll need to either:

- Upgrade to ASP.NET Core.
- Make your child action synchronous.

Comment: But it was working fine until I upgraded the Npgsql package.  So just wondering what causes this issue. The MVC version is still the same as the previous one.

Comment: > upgraded

Did they change from synchronous to asynchronous APIs?